# Static connection PDO

Tags: php, mysql, oop

Since I changed my classes to static and tried learning OOP. My PDO stopped working.

Do you guys have any clue? Since the PDO connection is in DBconnect is should work right?

Here is my code:

```php
<?php

Class Db{

    private static $dbHost;
    private static $dbUser;
    private static $dbPass;
    private static $dbName;
    private static $dbResult = null;
    public static $dbConnect = null;

    public static function connection(){

        self::$dbHost = '***';
        self::$dbUser = '***';
        self::$dbPass = '***';
        self::$dbName = '***';

        try{
            self::$dbConnect = new PDO('mysql:host='. self::$dbHost . ';dbname=' . self::$dbName,
                self::$dbUser,
                self::$dbPass);

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo 'Connection error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public static function query($sql, $array = []){

        self::$dbResult = self::$dbConnect->prepare($sql);

        self::$dbResult->execute($array);

    }

    public static function getOne(){

        return self::$dbResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public static function getAll(){

        return self::$dbResult->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public static function getCount(){

        return self::$dbResult->rowCount();
    }

}
```

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Comment: Clearly, when you are calling `query`, it is attempting to use `self::$dbConnect` and this has not been initialised. When do you call `Db::connection()` to initialise it?

Comment: @Martin I store the connection into the variable dbConnect.
self::$dbConnect = new PDO('mysql:host='. self::$dbHost . ';dbname=' . self::$dbName,
                self::$dbUser,
                self::$dbPass);

Comment: I know.  When do you execute the code that initialises it? Did you not read my comment

Comment: @Martin In my other class I use this:   public function __construct(){

        $this->connection = self::$dbConnect;

    }

Comment: Please read my words: _When do you run Db::connection()_?  Unless you run that static function, your `$dbConnect` variable is never set

Comment: I haven't ran Db::connection(); is that required? if I place it into an __construct and run the self::connection(); It stays the same

Comment: If you do not execute `Db::connection()` then the code that creates `$dbConnect` is never run.  `$dbConnect` is NOT created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our extended discussion in comments, this is due to the fact that you never create `$dbConnect` because you do not execute the function that does it (`Db::connection()`).

Simply run this somewhere before you try to use the other static functions, and your code will work:

```
Db::connection();
Db::query(...);
...
```